# SQL Mirroring Message "The mirroring connection to "address" has timed out for database "database"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, mirroring

Executing under `SQL Server 2016 SP2 (SP2-CU2-GDR) (KB4458621) enterprise edition`. Receiving error message

> "The mirroring connection to "address" has timed out for database".

Do not have a witness server.  We manually fail over if required.  I have followed the advice I have found online to change the `Partner Timeout value`. Still getting the message every 21 minutes no matter what value I have in partner timeout. For example, my current Partner Timeout value is 3000. If I am understanding correctly that is 50 minutes.  Network team says there are no problems with the network.  I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: You're going to need a network trace, but if it happens every 21 minutes it sounds like a firewall that is set to kill connections longer than 21 minutes. Network trace in a circular buffer from both sides so you can see +- 5 minutes from when the event occurs.

Comment: Thank you sir for the information.  I will take your advice to my network team.